# How to count embedded mongodb instances with condition (Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, conditional-statements

For example, I have a collection Categories which partly embedds articles:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("123123123"),
    "articles_fields" : [
            {
                    "title" : "Hello world!",
                    "published_on" : ISODate("2016-09-24"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("123123123")
            }
            {
                    "title" : "Hello hello!",
                    "published_on" : ISODate("2016-09-24"),
                    "_id" : ObjectId("123123123")
            }
    ],
    "name" : "Common",
    "slug" : "common"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("12312312"),
    "articles_fields" : [
            {
                    "title" : "Another article",
                    "published_on" : null,
                    "_id" : ObjectId("57e7b145d042ac3404e27ed0")
            }
    ],
    "slug" : "software",
    "name" : "Software"
}
```

How could I get how much published articles are related to one category (have "published_on" not equal NULL and not equal "" (empty field)). I am counting this in view.

I suppose it should be something like this:

```
category["articles_fields"].count(where(:published_on.ne => ["", null]))
```

PS. I know I can use `category.articles.published.count`, but I would like use only Categories collection with embedded articles.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It will get all the articles having published_on and will return the count for every category.

```
   db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
    {$unwind:'$articles_fields'},
    {$match:{"articles_fields.published_on":{$ne:null}}},
    {$group:{_id:"$_id",document:{$push: "$$ROOT"},count:{$sum:1}}}

    ])
```

Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57ea94886be4d87da7824d37"),
    "document" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57ea94886be4d87da7824d37"),
            "articles_fields" : {
                "title" : "Hello world!",
                "published_on" : ISODate("2016-09-24T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "_id" : "123123123"
            },
            "name" : "Common",
            "slug" : "common"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57ea94886be4d87da7824d37"),
            "articles_fields" : {
                "title" : "Hello hello!",
                "published_on" : ISODate("2016-09-24T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "_id" : "123123123"
            },
            "name" : "Common",
            "slug" : "common"
        }
    ],
    "count" : 2.0
}
```

P.S.: This is normal mongodb query as I am not much aware about rails syntax.